# Vue Router sub-routes not working as expected

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

When trying to get sub-routes to work using `vue-router`, my sub-routes are rendering the parent route component and not the declared component for that sub-route. It seems that a component **must** be declared for a parent route, or no component will be displayed at all. For instance, if I declare my routes like this:

```
Router.map({
    '/login': {
        component: Login
    },
    '/stations': {
        subRoutes: {
            '/': {
                component: Station
            },
            '/create': {
                component: CreateStation
            }
        }
    },
});
```

Nothing is displayed on any route. But if I declare my routes like this:

```
Router.map({
    '/login': {
        component: Login
    },
    '/stations': {
        component: Station,
        subRoutes: {
            '/create': {
                component: CreateStation
            }
        }
    },
});
```

My `stations/create` route displays the same component as the `stations` route. What gives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You still need to declare the `root` component for the `/stations` route, like this:

```
'/stations': {
    component: Station,
    subRoutes: {
        '/': {
            component: ListStations
        },
        '/create': {
            component: CreateStation
        }
    }
}
```

According to the documentation:

```
router.map({
  '/foo': {
    component: Foo,
    // add a subRoutes map under /foo
    subRoutes: {
      '/bar': {
        // Bar will be rendered inside Foo's <router-view>
        // when /foo/bar is matched
        component: Bar
      },
      '/baz': {
        // Same for Baz, but only when /foo/baz is matched
        component: Baz
      }
    }
  }
})
```

> Now, with the above configuration, when you visit /foo, nothing will
>   be rendered inside Foo's outlet, because no sub route is matched.

**Update:**

When you create subroutes, you are telling the parent component (in this case `Station`), that it will need to host some components inside its template. Station and CreateStation don't sit side by side, they have a parent-child relationship (in terms of routes).

That's why the component Station needs to have a `router-view` element in its template, and both `ListStations` and `CreateStation` will render inside it.

Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/naeg67da/329/

Comment: I tried that and it is only loading the `/stations` component view on `/` and `/create`. Any other ideas?

Comment: Are you 100% sure that you are loading the right component on CreateStation?

Comment: Yes, because if I don't use `subRoutes`, it works as expected.

Comment: I know what's wrong... Look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/naeg67da/329/, I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the help! So, basically, I will need to extract a parent component for my `subRoute` components to reside within. Got it.